# Google Group with No Owner

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

We publish a Chrome Extension in the Chrome Web Store. A few years ago we created a public Google Group so several of us could manage the listing. Inadvertently the original group owner has been deleted. The group seems to be orphaned and we can no longer manage the listing, add/remove people from the group, etc. In the Chrome Web Store they say the following about setting up group publishing:

- You can only set up group publishing once and create one group publisher account.

Any ideas as to how we can assign a member to be an owner of this orphaned group? Or create a new group for the listing?

Thanks!

Scott

Answer (score 3):

Once you create a group publishing account the developer account that is linked to it is permanent. You cannot change which group is linked to this account but you can still retain your personal publishing account and can publish from either your group or personal account. You will learn it all [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing)

To be the owner of this extension, you can create a new Google Group Account under the other publisher account, then try to contact the Google to transfer the ownership.

Here is the link: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer